# how to use PHP switch to evalutate multiple variables

Tags: php

I create a switch case where should be a different output based on the $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] variable and somehow I can't understand why is not working.

When I save and access the page I get a unexpected 'switch' (T_SWITCH) in error

Any idea how to fix this?

This is the switch I use:

```
switch($v['domainrenew']['msetupfee']){
  case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '-1' :
    echo $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'];
    break;
  case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '0' :
    echo "Gratis";
    break;
  case $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'] == '0' :
    echo "Gratis";
    break;
  default:
    echo $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] ;
}
```

And the full context where I try to use the switch

```
$mydata = getDomainsPrice();
foreach($mydata as $k => $v)
{
    $is_in_gtld = get_europa($k);
    if($is_in_gtld == 1)
    {
        echo "<tr>
        <td><span style=\"font-size: 16px !important;font-weight: 600;color: #1a202c;\">  $k  </span></td>
        <td class=\"dnone\" style=\"border-top: 1px dashed #e5e9f2;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;color: rgba(91, 88, 88, 0.9);\"> ".($v['domainregister']['msetupfee'] == '-1' ?  '2' : '1')." </td>
        <td style=\"border-top: 1px dashed #e5e9f2;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;color: rgba(91, 88, 88, 0.9);\">"  .($v['domainregister']['msetupfee'] == '-1' ? $v['domainregister']['qsetupfee']  : $v['domainregister']['msetupfee']).  $v['domainregister']['suffix'] . "</td>
        <td style=\"border-top: 1px dashed #e5e9f2;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;color: rgba(91, 88, 88, 0.9);\">" .($v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '-1' ? $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee']  : $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee']).  $v['domainrenew']['suffix'] . "</td> .
        <td class=\"dnone\" style=\"border-top: 1px dashed #e5e9f2;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 500;color: rgba(91, 88, 88, 0.9);\">" 
         switch($v['domainrenew']['msetupfee']){
            case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '-1' :
                echo $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'];
                break;
            case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '0' :
                echo "Gratis";
                break;
            case $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'] == '0' :
                echo "Gratis";
                break;
            default:
                echo $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] ;
        }
        "</td></tr>"
    ;}
}
```

Comment: _$v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'] == '0'_ will result in a boolean true creating duplicate switch cases.

Comment: The PHP documentation for [switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) didn't help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this [`switch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) work for you?

```
switch(true){ // test each case for value is true
    case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '-1' :
        echo $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'];
        break;
    case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '0' :
        echo "Gratis";
        break;
    case $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'] == '0' :
        echo "Gratis";
        break;
    default:
        echo $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] ;
}
```

Try it here: https://www.online-ide.com/cgRbitXLq3

---

A couple problems with your use of PHP `switch`. First...

*Typically* only the targeted value of the main expression is put in the `switch` `case` statement, such as:

```
// SUCCESS
$var = 0;
switch ($var) {
    case 0: // <-- looking for 0
    echo 'yay.';
    break;
    // other case statements
}
```

...not a conditional statement, such as:

```
// FAIL
$var = 0;
switch ($var) {
    case $var === 0: // <-- oops
    echo 'yay.';
    break;
    // other case statements
}
```

Second, the `switch` statement presented in the question code is attempting to evaluate **multiple variables** at once.

```
// FAIL
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = 1;
switch ($var1) { // <-- $var1
    case $var1 === 0: // <-- $var1
    echo 'var1 is 0';
    break;
    case $var2 === 0: // <-- $var2
    echo 'var2 is 0';
    break;
}
```

**You can use `switch` to evaluate multiple variables**, but the typical application of the `switch` won't work as intended. Instead use `true` as the main expression in the `switch` statement, and then use conditional statements in the `case`s:

```
// SUCCESS
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = 1;
switch (true) { // <-- put "true" here
    case $var1 === 0:
    echo 'var1 is 0';
    break;
    case $var2 === 0:
    echo 'var2 is 0';
    break;
}
```

The thing is, `switch` is matching the *calculated* value of the main expression: `switch (/*main expression*/)`, with the *calculated* value of `case` statements: `case: /*case statement*/:`. To further illustrate, consider this:

```
switch (4 + 7) { // === 11
    case 3 + 8: echo '(3 + 8) === 11'; break;
    case 4 + 8: echo '(4 + 8) === 12'; break;
}
```

Outputs:

```
(3 + 8) === 11
```

And:

```
switch (4 + 7) { // === 11
    case 6 + 5: echo '(6 + 5) === 11'; break;
    case 3 + 8: echo '(3 + 8) === 11'; break;
    case 4 + 8: echo '(4 + 8) === 12'; break;
}
```

Outputs:

```
(6 + 5) === 11
```

Also note, the `break` statement is optional, and, when a `case` is matched, the `break` statement in that matched `case` stops the `switch` from evaluating any other `case`s.

If no `break` statement is used, the `switch` will find a matching `case`, execute it, and all subsequent `case` statements whether they match or not:

```
switch (4 + 7) { // === 11
    case 3 + 8: echo '(3 + 8) === 11';
    case 4 + 8: echo '(4 + 8) === 12';
    case 6 + 5: echo '(6 + 5) === 11';
}
```

Outputs:

```
(3 + 8) === 11 (4 + 8) === 12 (6 + 5) === 11
```

That is, unless another break is encountered:

```
switch (4 + 7) { // === 11
    case 3 + 8: echo '(3 + 8) === 11 ';
    case 4 + 8: echo '(4 + 8) === 12 '; break;
    case 6 + 5: echo '(6 + 5) === 11 ';
}
```

Outputs:

```
(3 + 8) === 11 (4 + 8) === 12
```

---

```
<?php

$mydata = [
    ["domainrenew" => ["msetupfee" => -1, "qsetupfee" => 5]], 
    ["domainrenew" => ["msetupfee" => 0, "qsetupfee" => 0]], 
    ["domainrenew" => ["msetupfee" => 5, "qsetupfee" => 0]],
    ["domainrenew" => ["msetupfee" => 5, "qsetupfee" => 5]]
]; // getDomainsPrice();

foreach($mydata as $k => $v)
{
    $is_in_gtld = 1; //iget_europa($k);
    if($is_in_gtld == 1)
    {
        echo "<tr><td><span style=\"font-size: 16px !important;font-weight: 600;color: #1a202c;\">  $k  </span></td><td> "
        ;

        switch(true){ // test each case for value true
            case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '-1' :
                echo $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'];
                break;
            case $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] == '0' :
                echo "Gratis";
                break;
            case $v['domainrenew']['qsetupfee'] == '0' :
                echo "Gratis";
                break;
            default:
                echo $v['domainrenew']['msetupfee'] ;
        }

        echo " </td></tr>\n";
    }
}

?>
```

https://www.online-ide.com/cgRbitXLq3

Comment: thanks for clarification, it makes sense.
I still have a issue and I get unexpected '$var' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';'  when i use the corect switch code. if I put a . in front of $var is working but then I get a lot of dots from the foreach function. I ask to much if you show me based on my above context how the integrate the switch.

just learning...

Comment: I didn't think of that—no sweat.

Comment: It works, thank.
now I know what mnistakes I've made